# Linux Mint 16 randomly freezing and freezes always after suspend wakeup

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, suspend, freeze

I've just installed Linux Mint 16 Cinnamon on Dell Latitude E6420.
During an hour of use the desktop would become unresponsive and I was unable to access any TTY. It just froze up. The same thing happened again after a forced reboot.

I again booted up and it was fine for the whole session, an hour or so. I put the computer to sleep (suspend) and when woken up the next morning it would wake up frozen.

I've checked `/var/log/syslog` and found some things I can't understand. See times between 00:06 when computer was put to sleep and 07:57 when computer was woken up. Specifically this line:

```
Apr 17 07:57:55 NIX-E6420 kernel: [  547.146134] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
```

Why would Mint freeze user processes when its woken up?

```
Apr 16 23:57:47 NIX-E6420 modem-manager[793]: <info>  (ttyS4) closing serial port...
Apr 16 23:57:47 NIX-E6420 modem-manager[793]: <info>  (ttyS4) serial port closed
Apr 16 23:57:47 NIX-E6420 modem-manager[793]: <info>  (ttyS4) opening serial port...
Apr 16 23:57:53 NIX-E6420 NetworkManager[843]: <info> (eth0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
Apr 16 23:57:53 NIX-E6420 NetworkManager[843]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Apr 16 23:57:53 NIX-E6420 NetworkManager[843]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
Apr 16 23:57:53 NIX-E6420 NetworkManager[843]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
Apr 16 23:57:59 NIX-E6420 modem-manager[793]: <info>  (ttyS4) closing serial port...
Apr 16 23:57:59 NIX-E6420 modem-manager[793]: <info>  (ttyS4) serial port closed
Apr 16 23:57:59 NIX-E6420 modem-manager[793]: <info>  (ttyS4) opening serial port...
Apr 16 23:58:05 NIX-E6420 modem-manager[793]: <info>  (ttyS4) closing serial port...
Apr 16 23:58:05 NIX-E6420 modem-manager[793]: <info>  (ttyS4) serial port closed
Apr 16 23:59:46 NIX-E6420 dbus[498]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.timedate1' (using servicehelper)
Apr 16 23:59:46 NIX-E6420 dbus[498]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.timedate1'
Apr 16 23:59:46 NIX-E6420 dbus[498]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' (using servicehelper)
Apr 16 23:59:46 NIX-E6420 dbus[498]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1'
Apr 17 00:02:20 NIX-E6420 kernel: [  295.630421] nouveau W[   PFIFO][0000:01:00.0] INTR 0x01000000: 0x00000005
Apr 17 00:06:31 NIX-E6420 kernel: [  546.940568] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
Apr 17 00:06:31 NIX-E6420 kernel: [  546.942332] PM: Preparing system for mem sleep
Apr 17 07:57:55 NIX-E6420 NetworkManager[843]: <info> (eth0): carrier now OFF (device state 100, deferring action for 4 seconds)
Apr 17 07:57:55 NIX-E6420 kernel: [  547.146134] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Apr 17 07:57:55 NIX-E6420 kernel: [  547.147354] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Apr 17 07:57:55 NIX-E6420 kernel: [  547.148469] PM: Entering mem sleep
Apr 17 07:57:55 NIX-E6420 kernel: [  547.148546] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Apr 17 07:57:55 NIX-E6420 kernel: [  547.169317] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Apr 17 07:57:55 NIX-E6420 kernel: [  547.169368] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk
Apr 17 07:57:55 NIX-E6420 kernel: [  547.169394] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Apr 17 07:57:55 NIX-E6420 kernel: [  547.169651] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
Apr 17 07:57:55 NIX-E6420 kernel: [  547.186790] nouveau  [     DRM] suspending fbcon...
Apr 17 07:57:55 NIX-E6420 kernel: [  547.186793] nouveau  [     DRM] suspending display...
Apr 17 07:57:55 NIX-E6420 kernel: [  547.186813] nouveau  [     DRM] unpinning framebuffer(s)...
Apr 17 07:57:55 NIX-E6420 kernel: [  547.186902] nouveau  [     DRM] evicting buffers...
Apr 17 07:57:55 NIX-E6420 kernel: [  547.187841] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: suspend
```

Comment: I gave up on waiting for an answer and thus returned to Ubuntu.

Comment: This problem is pervasive not just under Mint. Linux in general is a lottery in terms of waking up from sleep. Right now I am breaking in a fresh install of Fedora 26 before upgrading more hosts in my organization, and it freezes in Mate desktop while waking up from a screen sleep, not even from a sleep state. I've seen KDE doing that in earlier versions and filed half a dozen bug reports, which all but have been ignored or closed unconfirmed. Linux hates sleep states.